# Server-side swift Vapor - redefinition of module Error

Tags: ios, swift, server-side, vapor

I am new to Vapor and server-side swift and have some trouble setting it up. When I follow the documentation of Vapor about how to set it up, [can be found here](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/hello-world/) everything works as expected in the terminal but when I try to build it, there are a lot of errors, as you can see in the attached screenshot. [Image of the errors showing in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er0rb.jpg).

I have tried to delete Xcode and reinstall it and spending some hours trying to find a solution on google. I did not find something that solved this problem.

I have done this multiple times with different projects and have used templates as well as just initializing it with: (The first to code snippets to not generate any errors)

```sh
vapor new ProjectName
```

And then opening it in Xcode using

```sh
vapor Xcode
```

When I am in the right folder. I have also tried to build it from the terminal using this command but similar error appears:

```sh
vapor build
```

This as well is runned when inside the folder.

Here are the versions that I have:

```
Vapor: 3.1.10
Homebrew: 2.2.12
Swift: 5.2
MacOS: 10.15.4
Xcode: 11.4
```

Thanks for your effort!

SOLUTION - THANKS TO 0xTim

Update the homebrew version to 2.2.13 and it works.

You do it using the following command in the terminal

```sh
brew update
```

If you want to check your current version then you could use

```sh
brew --version
```

Thanks for the answer 0xTime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with Homebrew and Xcode's Command Line Tools. If you update to Homebrew 2.2.13, this issue should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing/reinstalling Command-line tools

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```